# Can I start over in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Is there a way to start over?

No spoilers here, but after a certain point in the game I wish I had done something different, so I'd like to perhaps start over and make some different decisions based on my current game play experience.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The only way I know of to start over is to delete your save file. That will reset the game. You could probably back up the save onto a USB storage device first, if you wanted, because there's no visible way to "switch" between saves.

---

On the PS4, go into your settings, then go to the menu item labeled "Application Saved Data Management", and then delete the data for No Man's Sky to reset.

Comment: Okay thanks. Also, good tip for backup first. This tells me that if I were to lose my hard drive, I'd have to start all over anyway.

Comment: Wait, aren't there cloud saves on ps4?

Comment: @user1306322 Yes, but unless you have auto-upload enabled, you have to upload them manually.

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it just loaded me in a broken space station, I was literally driving around in the space station lol. My save was still there maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: You also need to have an active PS Plus subscription for the cloud storage.

Comment: @Winsorvy I think you have to make sure you clear all of the save data. I actually did it pretty early on in the game, and it worked just fine, but there were multiple files I had to delete.

Answer (score 3):

I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4x5fjt/how_do_you_restart_the_game/

explode13 mentioned removing the following folder: NMS(or the one inside actually) under the path: `%APPDATA%\HelloGames\NMS` . If you cannot find folder AppData, just type it in the bar and the continuation will apear. This worked for me and I got to the tutorial from the beginning of the game.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: the OP is asking about the PS4 version, but this could be useful for PC players.